# How to use EXTRACT_REGEXP to remove a substring

Tags: regex

I'm fairly new to a regular expression and need some help with using EXTRACT_REGEXP to remove a substring from an input string.

Input example:

```
geo.location.country.city.tier1
geo.location.country.city.tier2
```

Output example:

```
tier1
tier2
```

Comment: Why do you need regex for this?

Comment: What is `EXTRACT_REGEXP()`? Please add a language tag to the question.

Comment: There's no need for a regexp. Just use a string replacement function and replace `geo.location.country.city.` with an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this one. Demo ar [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/a730A6/3):

```
\.(\w+)(?:\s+|$)
```

- `\.` matches a dot `.` literally
- `()` is a capturing group
- `\w+` matches a word (`\w` is a letter\digit character, `+` means one or more)
- `(\w+)` captures a word
- `(?:)` is non-capturing group
- `\s+` is at least one empty character and `$` is end of the line
- these above putted around `|` means `\s+` *or* `$`

Answer (score 0):

The regex will be

```
"geo\.location\.country\.city\.(.+?)"
```

depends on your needs and platform.